# Regex to match certain expressions and exclude a specific one

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to have my perl script search for a specific pattern, but then exclude one possible result. The idea is as follows:

```
foreach my $line (@lines)
{
    if (($line =~ m/  Disk (\d+)(\d+)(\d+)/)
     || ($line =~ m/  Disk (\d+)(\d+)/)
     || ($line =~ m/  Disk (\d+)/)
     && ($line =~ /^(?:(?!  Disk 0).)*$/)
    ) {
        print("here\n");
    }
}
# if the line contains anything like "Disk 1", "Disk 20", or "Disk 300"
# it will print "here" - but if it is "Disk 0" it will not.
```

When I execute the script it gets stuck on this part and never completes the script. Is this the correct syntax?

My regex is probably a bit messy as I'm pretty new to perl syntax so if there is a way to clean up that if statement please let me know, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
if ( $line =~ m/Disk [1-9]\d*/ ) {
```

Will match "Disk 1", "Disk 300", etc. but not "Disk 0".

Incidentally - brackets are capture groups. You have those in your regular expression, but don't seem to be using them (So I have omitted them).

Also `(\d+)(\d+)(\d+)` is 3 occurrences of *one or more* digits. This is almost certainly not what you actually mean, and it won't work anyway, because the first group will capture all but two of the digits.

e.g.:

```
my $string = "123456789";
my @captured = $string =~ m/(\d+)(\d+)(\d+)/;
print join ("\n", @captured);
```

Will print:

```
1234567
8
9
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Greatly reduced the Regex time as that was also an issue